# I would want to vs. I would like to

Tags: meaning, grammar

Isn't it a mistake to use such construction: **I would want to....** instead of **I would like to...**?
Or is it acceptable but there is a difference between those two constructions or maybe it depends on the context?

I am asking about it because I saw this form **"I would want to"** many times used in English translations of subtitles in Chinese and Korean dramas. And I was wondering if it's not a mistake.

I can't find a proper answer for that on the Internet, so I thought you guys could help me. :-)

Comment: What is your *exact* context? For most purposes you should probably stick to saying *what you would **like** to do*. But, consider *I will come to your party tonight, but I probably won't stay long. If John isn't there to drive us back, **I would want to** leave before midnight to catch the last bus.* I find ***want*** better than ***like*** there, because idiomatically speaking ***I would like** [to do X]* has become so strongly associated with *what the speaker wants **at time of utterance***. But in my example, it's what I ***might*** want [hypothetical future], not what I want ***now***.

Answer (score 8):

'I would like to ...' (and especially the contracted form, 'I'd like to', in conversation) is an idiomatic expression expressing a desire, from a daydream to what is almost a demand.

- 'I'd like to have a cruiser in the Caribbean.' [probably daydreaming]
- 'I would like to have a brighter garden.' [usually, far from being a pipedream]
- 'I would like to speak to the manager.' [usually a brusque request]

There are common extensions:

- 'I'd like to think that my parents would understand if I changed careers.' [I'd hope ...]
- 'I'd like to see Ben do a triple Salchow!' [Fat chance]

................

'I would want to' on the other hand is rare except in an obviously stated conditional use:

- 'If I lived here, I would want to move out as soon as I could.'
- 'I would want to buy a smaller car if the kids moved out.'

Comment: Again, cleanly done.